# Android MediaCodec fails to start

Tags: android, encoding, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to use MediaCodec to generate a mp4 file from a set of bitmaps i have.
After a lot of coding and testing I noticed that no example existent on internet or whatever work on the Android Studio emulator, but they do work in both of my real phone (android 7 and 9)... So i kept develoing only testing on real phones.

after a lot of coding and testing i got a working coding (working for both of my phones but crashing for the android emulator) and deployed to production.

My has been online for a couple of months and I have around 150 daily users, but around 30% of them are getting the same crash i noticed on the android emulator. so that isn't a limitation of the emulator.

E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.encoder] configureCodec returning error -38
    signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0x80001001, resetting...

```
private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType) {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
            if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
            for (String type : types) {
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                    return codecInfo;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = EncoderUtils.selectCodec("video/avc");
MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName()).encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
```

`format` has the following keys

```
"color-format" -> {Integer@17131} 21
"i-frame-interval" -> {Integer@17133} 3
"mime" -> "video/avc"
"profile" -> {Integer@17136} 8
"width" -> {Integer@17138} 928
"bitrate-mode" -> {Integer@17140} 0
"bitrate" -> {Integer@17142} 3500000
"language" -> "eng"
"frame-rate" -> {Integer@17146} 12
"max-input-size" -> {Integer@17140} 0
"height" -> {Integer@17149} 1152
```

then i get the following exception:

```
Non-fatal Exception: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80001001
       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(MediaCodec.java)
       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1960)
       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1889)
       at com.tomatedigital.lottogram.util.EncoderUtils.start(EncoderUtils.java:98)
       at com.tomatedigital.lottogram.service.LottogramService$3.run(LottogramService.java:329)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

while the logcat prints:

```
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.encoder] configureCodec returning error -38
    signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0x80001001, resetting...
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
W/AMessage: failed to deliver message as target handler 7 is gone.
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.encoder] configureCodec returning error -38
    signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0x80001001, resetting...
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
```

there is no such reference to 0x80001001 error anywhere i could find. what does it mean? how to solve it? does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Those dimensions look pretty suspect... different OEMs supply different codecs, it wouldn't surprise me if some of them didn't support those dims.